# StringModifier - Reverses a string and returns information about it

Tags: java, performance, beginner

I have been coding in Java for about a month now and I'm seeking advice for my program on things I can improve. This project was mainly made for me to incorporate all the new things I learned and utilize them effectively. I appreciate any feedback :).

About the program itself, it takes in a string and reverses it. It also counts the amount of characters (spaces, numbers, letters, and other characters) and it checks if the typed string is a palindrome or not.

## Main class

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        
        application.printInstructions();
        application.programLoop();
        application.printSeparator(); // Prints a separator before the program terminates.
    }
}
```

## Application class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String definedString;

    // Main function for reversing the string.
    private String reverseString(String string) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();
        for (int i = string.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            stringBuilder.append(charArray[i]);
            
        }
        
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    // Processes the output and prints it out.
    private void processInput() {
        
        printSeparator();
        System.out.println("Reversed String: " + reverseString(definedString));
        printSeparator();
        
        countCharacters(definedString);
        isPalindrome();
        programLoop();
        
    }

    // Main program loop.
    public boolean programLoop() {
        System.out.print("-: ");
        definedString = userInput.nextLine();
        
        // If the input isn't the break command, it processes and prints out the results.
        while (!definedString.equals("!break")) {
            processInput();
            
        }
        
        return false;
        
    }

    // Prints starting instructions.
    public void printInstructions() {
        System.out.println("StringModifier - Reverses a string and returns information about it.");
        System.out.println("Type '!break' to exit");
        
    }

    // Counts the amount of characters in the reversed string.
    private void countCharacters(String string) {
        char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();
        int letters = 0;
        int numbers = 0;
        int spaces = 0;
        int other = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isSpaceChar(charArray[i])) {
                spaces++;

            } else if (Character.isDigit(charArray[i])) {
                numbers++;

            } else if (Character.isLetter(charArray[i])) {
                letters++;

            } else {
                other++;

            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Spaces: " + spaces);
        System.out.println("Numbers: " + numbers);
        System.out.println("Letters: " + letters);
        System.out.println("Other: " + other);
    }
    
    // Adds a separating line.
    public void printSeparator() {
        System.out.println("—————————————————————————————————————");
        
    }
    
    // Checks if the string is a palindrome.
    public void isPalindrome() {
        
        if (definedString.equals(reverseString(definedString))) {
            System.out.println("Is a Palindrome: Yes");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Is a Palindrome: No");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rewrite your `reverseString` to use the built-in [StringBuilder.reverse()](https://devdocs.io/openjdk%7E15/java.base/java/lang/stringbuilder#reverse()).

Your class structure is a little bit mixed up. The `Application` and `Main` classes currently have some of the same obligations. Rephrase this to, perhaps,

- a `Main` class that only cares about display and does your program loop
- a `StringInfo` class that does no integrated display in its logic methods, and has accessor functions for reversed (returning a string and not printing), isPalindrome (returning a boolean and not printing), spaceCount (returning an integer and not printing), etc.

### Suggested

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    final Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app = new Main();

        printInstructions();
        app.programLoop();
        printSeparator();
    }

    // Prints starting instructions.
    public static void printInstructions() {
        System.out.println("StringModifier - Reverses a string and returns information about it.");
        System.out.println("Type '!break' to exit");
    }

    // Main program loop.
    public void programLoop() {
        // If the input isn't the break command, it processes and prints out the results.
        while (true) {
            printSeparator();
            System.out.print("-: ");
            String definedString = userInput.nextLine();
            if (definedString.equals("!break"))
                break;
            (new StringInfo(definedString)).dump();
        }
    }

    // Adds a separating line.
    public static void printSeparator() {
        System.out.println("—————————————————————————————————————");
    }
}

public class StringInfo {
    public final String definedString;

    public StringInfo(String definedString) {
        this.definedString = definedString;
    }

    public String reversed() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(definedString);
        builder.reverse();
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public long nSpaces() {
        return definedString.chars().filter(ch -> Character.isSpaceChar(ch)).count();
    }

    public long nLetters() {
        return definedString.chars().filter(ch -> Character.isLetter(ch)).count();
    }

    public long nDigits() {
        return definedString.chars().filter(ch -> Character.isDigit(ch)).count();
    }

    public long nOther() {
        return definedString.chars().filter(ch -> !(
               Character.isSpaceChar(ch)
            || Character.isLetter(ch)
            || Character.isDigit(ch)
        )).count();
    }

    public boolean isPalindrome() {
        return definedString.equals(reversed());
    }

    public void dump() {
        System.out.printf("Reversed String: %s%n", reversed());
        System.out.printf("Spaces: %d%n", nSpaces());
        System.out.printf("Digits: %d%n", nDigits());
        System.out.printf("Letters: %d%n", nLetters());
        System.out.printf("Other: %d%n", nOther());

        System.out.print("Is a palindrome: ");
        if (isPalindrome()) System.out.println("yes");
        else System.out.println("no");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I do have one question though. Why is it preferable to use return statements instead of just printing it out from the method? My thought is to probably have flexible values which I can use anywhere in my program.

Comment: @Kimosauraus Why prefer return over printing? Because you might want to re-use things like string reverting or character counting later in a program with a GUI, or in a web server or whatever. Make it a habit to separate information processing from input/output.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for your answer.